# How I can add the day when the day was min and the day was max

Tags: python, python-3.x, helper, solver

A question states that I am making a program where the user adds the number of days he invested in the stock market. After that, he adds the prices and shows the highest and lowest price with the addition of the day at the highest and lowest price.

```
N = int(input("Namuber of days: "))
x_list = []

for i in range(N):
    x = float(input("Enter a set of stock prices on day{}: ".format(i+1)))
    x_list.append(x)

print(max(x_list))
print(min(x_list))
```

Comment: So... Whats the error here? Where is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to print the `index` of the `max` and `min` prices instead.

```
print(x_list.index(max(x_list)))
print(x_list.index(min(x_list)))
```

Comment: How do you know this is what OP is asking?

Comment: Don't answer such questions, you are encouraging new users to ask such kind of questions.

Comment: See the title. It's also a part of the question :)

Comment: :) The "question" then is how to post a day, you simply print the index? There is no explanation or anything how this code correlates to days, you dont save the day along with the value of the stock? What even is your "answer" :)